# Schengen transit visa

Tags: schengen-visas, morocco, kenyan-citizens

I'm a Kenyan citizen and I hold a valid Moroccan visa. I'm due to travel to Morocco from Kenya, East Africa via Paris,France later on next month for tourism purposes, will I be needing a transit visa for France given that I will only be having a layover for 3hrs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: @GoodDeeds indeed this answers my question, thank you very much.

Comment: If that solved your problem, you can select Yes and Submit, and the question will be marked as resolved.